# How do we convey a web page or app for different age groups?

Tags: ux-designer, readability, responsive, age

A children's book is colorful and has large letters. At the same time, when we grow up, letter size is reduced by age, and in old age there is much less color and letters are larger. So, if a page is for adults and for seniors, how do you design for better communication? How can we achieve this in UX Design ...?

Comment: Keep in mind that older users already might have put some settings to improve readability on their device, like changing the zoom on their browser or overall displaying larger fonts on the system.
Designing your application with bigger letters might be overdoing it for them.

Comment: Older people tend to read more because they can comprehend more. The reason why most children book's words are huge is because there are far less words and to negate the empty space, the letters have to grow.

Comment: Yeah, as I get older they keep making the text smaller!

Comment: You could always rely on the standard to be inclusive of the majority. And maybe offer some form of customization where the user can increase the size of the font (just like IOS and Android devices)

Answer (score 1):

It's important to remember that regardless of the targeted demographic, simplicity in UX is valuable. You're correct in saying that designing for children generally involves brighter colors and larger text, but there's no rule against doing the same thing for adults as long as it doesn't look unprofessional.

My advice would be to find a balance between child-friendly and adult-friendly that focuses on simplicity without being "offensively simple" or childlike.